Why TimeZoneInfo returns different data on Windows than Mac/Linux?
When trying to get Offset information from past date, TimeZoneInfo is returning wrong information only in Windows.
The following .NET code reproduce the issue:
let dt = DateTimeOffset.Parse("1904-05-11T08:45:30Z")
let timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/Madrid")

timeZone.GetUtcOffset(dt).Hours //Should be 0, but return 2 on Windows.

My hypothesis is that the timezone data in windows is not updated, but I did not found any way to update it manually.

There exists two major time zone databases:

IANA
Windows

They do not share the same time zone names, nor the same data.  Although there is some somewhat ad-hoc mapping that can be done to translate a time zone name from one to another.  Such a translation is generally pretty good, but not 100% accurate.  Accuracy tends to degrade sharply with dates that are pre 1970.
.NET uses the Windows time zone database.  This database has a 2h offset for your time and place.
Mac/Linux uses the IANA time zone database.  This database has a 0h offset for your time and place.

But Windows result is wrong, so I should just accept that? Or should I add a lot of conditionals to my code to verify that?

IANA doesn't guarantee it is right for pre-1970 dates either.  In fact in the past few years there are cases where the IANA maintainers have purposefully made pre-1970 data wrong for reasons I still don't understand.  I'm not currently aware of a dependable source of global data for 1904.  Personally I think the UN should maintain a database.  But they don't.
